# sprintf replacement for embedded systems

Tags: c, embedded

In my current embedded system, I don't have the access to the standard library of sprintf. Is there a replacement ?

I would like to convert a `float` to bytes and send that in the UART to be read.

The float comes from an ADC as temperature and I would like to send "ADC read= temperature"

I'm using blackfin 533 DSP.

Comment: Which stdio.h functions are available?

Comment: I can't use it, it will increase the overhead in terms of size in the firmware

Comment: You can avoid `sprintf` if you send raw bytes. BTW Are you sure data from ADC are `float`...?

Comment: @Andre You can't use the st library at all?

Comment: @2501 no, it will increase the size of the executable. and that's not needed

Comment: @LPs, how would I represent 1.5f into ASCII string, to display it over UART

Comment: Are you sending data to an ASCII terminal or to a slave device? Not clear.

Comment: @LPs the receiver should decode the bytes and then convert them to float, which is something that I don't need to do, because it needs modification in the other side

Comment: Is the receiver an higher level device? Use a fixed-point decimal and transmit it as an integer. Simple to reconvert back to float on the other side.

Comment: Can you implement your own?